# Read tdms file with file dialog

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a problem opening a TDMS file from a user dialog:

```
    from nptdms import TdmsFile as td
    import numpy as np


def browse_TDMS_file ():
            global path
            path = filedialog.askopenfilename(multiple = True, 
                                                   initialdir = r"//C:",
                                                   title = 'XXXXXXXX',filetypes = (("TDMS","*tdms"),))
            label = tk.Label(root, text = (str(path)))
            canvas1.create_window(450, 97, window=label, width = 200)
        enter code here
    
    tdms_file = TdmsFile.open()
    group = tdms_file.groups()
    channel = group[0].channels()
```

How to solve this problem. I would like to create an application that will process data from TDMS (create a graph) on a user-specified TDMS file. The GUI will be used for this.

Comment: Which problem do you have with opening a TDMS file from a user dialog?

Comment: I have a problem opening the file and processing the data

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: When it points to the file to open, it doesn't do that. This is what I usually found

tdms_file = TdmsFile.read ("my_file.tdms")

Where we give the constant path to the file.

Comment: What does it do instead?

Comment: TypeError: open() missing 1 required positional argument: 'file'

Comment: Why don't you pass a file name to `TdmsFile.open()`?

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: By writing it between the opening and closing parentheses like you showed in your earlier comment.

Comment: It doesn't work in this form either:

tdms_file = TdmsFile.read(browse_TDMS_file).

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '<function browse_TDMS_file at 0x000001FD1F6BEEE0>'

Comment: You need to pass a string, not a function. It looks like the variable `path` might be what you should pass.

Comment: 'tdms_file = TdmsFile.read(path)'
name 'path' is not defined